# How can I permanently disable App Store notifications in Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur

I found it impossible to disable update notifications for apps - notifcation centre does not provide App Store option, disabling "automatically check for updates" only disables checking for OSX updates. Is there something I'm missing or is there a way to solve it in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable Notification Center permanently type

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
```

and

```
killall NotificationCenter
```

into the terminal.

To reenable Notification Center, type

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
```

Go to this directory:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/
```

and double click Notification Center app.

Comment: Ok, so you recommend to cut down all notifications in the system to get rid of App Store notifications?